# Laravel 5.6 database operations in model

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

**I have a controller called UserController, in that controller i am inserting a row of data to table "user" like this**

```
$user             = new UsersModel();
$user->first_name = $request->input('firstName');
$user->last_name  = $request->input('lastName');
$user->about      = $request->input('userAbout');
$user->join_date  = date('Y-m-d');
$user->save();
```

**My Question is, can i write this in my model called UsersModel???
Something Like,**

( The insertData($data) is called from controller class.)

```
class UsersModel extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['id','first_name','last_name','about','image','join_date','created_at','updated_at'];
 protected $table    = 'users';

    public function insertData($data) {
       // nb: $data contains values of fileds
       // insert operation
       //also return some values
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not. Just make sure you pass in the right data and do some checks. There's a reason the phrase "fat models, slim controllers" exists.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define your own function when you can already do it through Eloquent by simply calling the static method `create` magically:

```
$ref = UsersModel::create([
     'col' => 'val'
]);
```

where `$ref` contains the information about the created data.

No need to reinvent the wheel in this instance.

However, your own custom method is possible too, make sure your function is defined as `static` to allow you to use without an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can 
you need to call the function from the controller like this

```
$data = ['YOUR ARRAY'];
$this->usersModel = new UsersModel();
$this->usersModel->insertData($data);
```

You can also do with static function

**In Model**

```
public static function insertData($data) {
```

**In Controller**

```
UsersModel::insertData($data);
```

[Insert function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts)

```
UsersModel::insert($data);
```